# Server side meteor collections aren't visible on client side

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I have collections that are published on the server side, and use iron router's waitOn to subscribe to these collections. However, on the client side I can never see any reference to the collections defined on the server side. The only way I can access them is by defining the collection on the client side (devices = new Meteor.Collection('devices')), but I don't see anyone doing this in their examples online. Here is the code:

Client Code:

```
Router.route('/devices', {
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('devices', Meteor.user()._id),
        ];
    },
    action: function() {
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Server Side:

```
Devices = new Mongo.Collection("devices");
Devices.allow({
    'insert': function (userId, doc) {
        if (userId === doc.accountId) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    'update': function (userId, doc) {
        if (userId === doc.accountId) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
});
Meteor.publish('devices', function(id) {
    return Devices.find({accountId: id});
});
```

I have removed autopublish, and from the examples online, I should just be able to reference Devices.find({}). Instead, I have to use devices = new Meteor.Collection('devices') which then causes issues since if I call this again, it will say I already have a collection called devices. Does anyone know why I can't reference Devices?

Comment: devices = new Meteor.Collection('devices') will create a MongoDB collection called devices on the server; on the client, this creates a cache connected to the server. devices = new Meteor.Collection(null) would create a client side collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't reference it on the client side is that you haven't made the collection available to the client.

Leave the `.allow` and `.publish` methods on the server side, but move your collection creation to the lib folder to make it available on both the client and server.

/lib/collections.js:

```
Devices = new Mongo.Collection("devices");
```